# C++ understand copy constructor

Tags: c++

There is something that I am not able to understand. Look at this kind of main:

```
class C {
 public:
  C() { cout << "C0 "; }
  C(const C&) { cout << "Cc"; }
};

class D {
 public:
  C c;
  D() { cout << "D0 "; }
  D(const D&) { cout << "Dd"; }
};

int main() {

  D x; cout << endl;
  D y(x); cout << endl;
  return 0;

}

//output is:
C0 D0
C0 Dd
```

---

I agree on the fact that `D x` gives `C0 D0` as output because in class D there is a call to the default constructor of `C` and then the object `D` is created.

Also `D y(x)` is like `D y = x` where (like before) C is created (so output C0) and the the copy constructor is called. Why doesn't the `Cc` appear? If you consider this code:

```
class C {
 public:
  C() { cout << "C0 "; }
  C(const C&) { cout << "Cc"; }
};

class D {
 public:
  C c;
  D() { cout << "D0 "; }
};

int main() {

  D x; cout << endl;
  D y(x); cout << endl;
  return 0;

}

//output is:
C0 D0
Cc
```

Why now the output is `Cc`?

The code are equal except for the fact that there isn't a definition of the copy constructor on D. Saying that `D y(x)` is like `D y = x` I'd expect like before that C is created (calling default constructor so output `C0`) and then no text because `D(const D&)` is **not** defined.

Maybe I am misunderstanding copy constructors. How are they called in this case?

Comment: What you're looking for is ["implicitly declared copy constructor"](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor#Implicitly-declared_copy_constructor)

Comment: @DrewDormann exactly that ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Also `D y(x)` is like `D y = x`

It is not LIKE it, it IS EXACTLY it. The latter is just syntax sugar for the first.

> where (like before) `C` is created (so output `C0`) and the the copy constructor is called

No, the `C` copy constructor is not called in that case.  You did not define your `D` copy constructor to call the `C` copy constructor, so the `c` member is default-constructed instead, which is why you see `C0`, but since you did not actually copy `c`, you don't see `Cc`.

You are expecting the `D` copy constructor to *automatically* call the copy constructors of `D`'s members, but that is simply NOT the case.  You have to *explicitly* define that behavior yourself, eg:

```
D(const D &src) : c(src.c) { }
```

> Why doesn't the `Cc` appear?

Because your `C` copy constructor is not called at all in your `D y(x)` example.

Comment: A non-sense question. I've read again carefully what you've written and I realized the answer by myself (and a test on visual studio confirmed it). Thanks again

Answer (score 6):

In the first case your D Copy constructor needs to explicitly call the C copy constructor.

```
D(const D &d) :  c(d.c) 
{ cout << "Dd"; }
```

In the 2nd case, since you do not define a D copy-ctor, the compiler generates one for you.

To make this clearer, add an extra int to both C and D.

```
static int counter;
class C {
 public:
  int index;
  C() { index = ++counter; cout << "C0 "; }
  C(const C&) { index = c.counter; cout << "Cc"; }
};

class D {
 public:
  int dcounter;
  C c;
  D() { dcounter = ++counter; cout << "D0 "; }
  D(const D&) : dcounter(D.dcounter)
{ cout << "Dd"; }
};
```

Now, step thru with a debugger, or add more printfs().
When you do D y(x), you will see that the member c in y isn't copied from anything - just constructed.

Comment: You are correct. Sombody edited my answer and put in the part with operator=(). I've removed that now.

Answer (score 3):

When you define a custom copy constructor, it does what you tell it to; you don't tell it to copy the `c` member, so it doesn't, hence `C0`. Indeed, if you were to a value in that `c` you'd see it's not even available in the newly copied member.

When you don't have a custom copy constructor, the default one that gets invoked invokes copy constructors for members it copies. In this case, you would see a value end up in the copied instance.

Comment: Thank you. So in the first case my D(const D&), since I didn't tell him to do a copy, it didn't copy the items. Correct? I thought that the copy was made by default and I didn't have to write it

Comment: That is correct, you did not tell the `D` copy constructor to make a copy of `c`, so it didn't. You have to invoke member copy constructors yourself in the member initialization list.